# /g (global) tag not working in jquery .replace function

Tags: jquery, replace, find

```
<span id="description">
 <?php echo $itemdesc ?>
</span>
```

The above PHP outputs part of the URL that displays something like this:

```
 This%2520is%2520the%2520 %2520thing%2520 %2520purchased%2520
```

And what I want is this:

```
 This is the thing purchased
```

Here's my code. My problem is the /g tag (global) doesn't seem to be working.

```
<script>
  oldhtml = $('#description').html();
  var newhtml = oldhtml.replace("%2520"/g, " ");
  $('#description').html(newhtml);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ", add `/` to cover regex.
That is `/%2520/g`.
When you use `"%2520'/g, there is no regex to associate`g` with.

```
var newhtml = oldhtml.replace(/%2520/g, " ");
$('#description').html(newhtml);
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
.replaceAll("%2520"," ");
```